# execution stops at the given line

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on URL validation in CodeIgniter, found a code in one of the stack overflow posts
here's the code

```
function validate_url($url)
    {
        $pattern = "/^((ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/|~/|/)?([w]{2}([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,5}))(:[\d]{1,5})?/";
        if (!preg_match($pattern, $url))
        {
            $this->set_message('validate_url', 'The URL you entered is not correctly formatted.'); // execution stops at this line.
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I think I'm doing something wrong here. The execution stops at the line

> "$this->set_message..."

. can you please point it out?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I forgot "form_validation->" before set_message. So the code become "$this->form_validation->set_message".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of `set_message` is wrong it us used with `$this->form_validation->`

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('validate_url', 'The URL you entered is not correctly formatted.');
```

Read manual [set_message()](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/form_validation.html)

And Don't forget to call `form_validation` library

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use set_flashdata for this kind of purpose.

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('validate_url','your message');
```